# How to store chat history in web chat app

Tags: php, chat

I am working on a company intranet which has an embedded chat client so all users can talk to each over the intranet.

I'm using a guide from http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket to work on the basis of the chat client and I have it all working so that users can talk to each other privately. What I want to be able to do though is maintain the chat history if they refresh their page or if they switch between pages.

Not sure what the best way to store it is, whether in a database, store it with the socket information in the chat server or store it in a session or cookie array.

Comment: You should just store it in a database. Any database would do.

Answer (score 3):

Storing the chat history in Redis would be ideal.  There are several redis clients available for PHP: http://redis.io/clients#php.

Depending on the amount of traffic you get, you could then archive old chats to MySQL or some other database at a later time.  You'd want to use Redis while the conversation is active as you can write to it and read from it extremely quickly (great for chatting over sockets).

Here's an example of using PHP & Redis for a chat service with step-by-step examples: http://www.9lessons.info/2014/01/getting-started-with-redis-chatting.html